# Amazon Linux再起動時にUnicornが自動的に起動しない

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, unicorn

Amazon Linux再起動時にUnicornが自動的に起動されません。

環境
OS Amazon Linux
ruby 2.2.3
rails 4.2.3
nginx 1.9.11
unicorn 5.0.1

unicornの起動スクリプトは`etc/init.d/`にファイル名`unicorn`として配置しランレベル3と5をオンにしています。
`sudo service unicorn start`後に問題なく起動できており、`sudo service unicorn stop`で停止もできています。しかし、再起動させるとunicornが起動していません。また、起動していないのになぜかpidファイルはあります。`sudo service unicorn stop`コマンド実行時はpidファイルが消えてその後`sudo service unicorn start`を実行できていますのでなぜpidファイルだけ残っているのか分かりません。

起動スクリプトは下記の通りとなっています。

```
#!/bin/sh
#
#
# unicorn - this script starts and stops the unicorn daemon
#
# chkconfig: - 85 15
# description: Unicorn is Rack Rails Server

# Source function library.
. /etc/rc.d/init.d/functions

PROG_NAME=unicorn
APP_ROOT=/home/ec2-user/rails_test
ENV=production
PID_FILE=/var/run/rails-app-unicorn.pid
LOCK_FILE=/var/lock/subsys/unicorn
CONF="${APP_ROOT}/config/unicorn.rb"
CMD="bundle exec unicorn -c ${CONF} -E ${ENV} -D"

export PATH=/home/ec2-user/.rbenv/shims:/home/ec2-user/.rbenv/bin:$PATH

cd $APP_ROOT || exit 1

case $1 in
    start)
        daemon $CMD
        touch $LOCK_FILE
        ;;
    stop)
        killproc -p $PID_FILE $PROG_NAME -QUIT
        rm -f $LOCK_FILE
        ;;
    restart)
        killproc -p $PID_FILE $PROG_NAME -USR2
        ;;
    *)
    echo >&2 "Usage: $0 <start|stop|restart>"
    exit 1
    ;;
esac
```

ご指摘やアドバイス頂けると助かります。
よろしくお願いします。

追記

原因が分かりました。
unicorn起動時にpostgresが起動していなければならないところ、postgresが起動していなかったのが原因でした。postgresの起動優先度が98に設定されているので起動スクリプトの`# chkconfig: - 85 15`を`# chkconfig: - 99 15`に変更することで無事に起動できました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

start 時に /var/lock/subsys/unicorn ファイルを作成しないと、OS シャットダウン時のサービス停止処理で service unicorn stop が実行されず、pid ファイルが残ります。
OS 起動時の service unicorn start で pid ファイルが既に存在するので、起動しないのだと思います。

(2016/02/29 01:27 追記) /etc/init.d/unicorn トレースログ取得方法
スクリプトの最初の方に追記:

```
exec 3>>/tmp/unicorn-trace.log
BASH_XTRACEFD=3
set -x
```

スクリプトの最後の方(exit する前)に追記:

```
set +x
unset BASH_XTRACEFD
exec 3>&-
```

Comment: ご指摘の通り、start時にLOCKファイルを作成しましたが、LINUXを再起動してみるとunicornが実行されていませんでした。また、PIDファイルとLOCKファイルが残ったままになっていました。stop実行時にPIDファイルとLOCKファイルを削除するように実装しているのでシャットダウン時にstopがなぜか呼ばれていないようです。stopが呼ばれないその他の要因何かありますでしょうか?

Comment: シンボリックリンク /etc/rc6.d/K15unicorn, /etc/rc6.d/S00killall は存在しますか？

Comment: 確認したところどちらもあります。

Comment: シェルスクリプトを echoデバッグ(printfデバッグ)するとか、"set -x" でトレースして調べるか。

まずは、/etc/init.d/unicorn で "set -x" して OS 再起動したときに stop が実行されていないのか、実行されているけれどエラーで途中終了しているのか、調べたく。
スクリプトの修正箇所は回答に追記しました。

それでもわからなければ、同様に /etc/rc.d/rc をデバッグする必要があるのですが、こちらは記述を間違えると OS 起動／停止できなくなる可能性があります。

Comment: もしかして、stop は実行されているけれど、killproc でシグナルを送ってから実際に pid ファイルが消えるまで、秒単位で時間がかかっているのではないでしょうか。
想定シナリオ: OS再起動→stop 実行→killproc でシグナルを送りロックファイル削除→pid ファイルが消える前にリブート処理→OS起動→start 実行→pid ファイルが存在するので unicorn は起動せず、その成否に関わらずロックファイル作成。

Comment: 教えて頂いた方法でログを取ることができました。終了時、起動時共にログが出力されているようです。ログを確認してみましたが私ではよく分かりません。起動時にfailureとあるので失敗していることは分かりました。
GitHubにログファイルをアップしましたので確認頂けると助かります。
https://github.com/Kiiroitory/unicorn_start_log/tree/master

Comment: トレースログの情報ありがとうございます。
ログでは stop, start とも実行されていて、start 時に $CMD が実行されています。
予想していた、「pid ファイルが残っているために $CMD が実行されない」ということではなく、「OS再起動後、$CMD が実行されているけれど、起動に失敗している」状況のようです。
シェルスクリプト側ではリターンコードが 1 (失敗)ということしかわかりません。
$CMD (bundle exec)起動時のデバッグログなどは確認できませんでしょうか。

ちなみに、star 時の pid_file が正しく認識されていないので、「daemon --pidfile $PID_FILE $CMD」とした方がいいと思います。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。ご指摘の通りコマンドを修正します。
unicorn.stderr.logを新たにGitHubに追加しました。末尾の1107行からがスタート時のログと思います。`PG::ConnectionBad`というエラーがあります。

Comment: [このディスカッションをチャットで続行](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36343/discussion-between-taichi-yanagiya-and-penlight)しましょう。